# Spring cloud sleuth dependencies throwing RibbonLoadBalancerClientException in Spring boot stack application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

We are planning to integrate spring sleuth in our Spring cloud microservices application. However when a Service A makes a call to Service B using RestTemplate we are getting RibbonLoadBalancerClient exception. Please find the stack trace below.

```
ResponseObject genericResponse = restTemplate.exchange(expandedUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(null), ResponseObject.class).getBody();
Logger.log(DEBUG, "getDetails returned {} ", response);
return genericResponse.getData().getInformation();
```

The version are are using is as below

- Spring Boot   :  springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
- Spring Sleuth : spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:1.2.4.RELEASE
- Spring cloud dependencies : spring-cloud-services dependencies:1.2.0.RELEASE,
  spring-cloud-dependencies:Brixton.RELEASE

---

Exception - stacktrace : 
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: **org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/springframework/cloud/client/ServiceInstance;Lorg/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/LoadBalancerRequest;)Ljava/lang/Object;| at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)| at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)| at** org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)|

Comment: Brixton is very old. Your likely using versions that don't work together. Let the BOM manage all the versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the release train to manage versions. Also Brixton is a very old release train. Please upgrade and don't set library versions manually.